# Google Sheets - ARRAYFORMULA with embedded QUERY and dynamic cell reference as Query Contains

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I've got a Google Sheets file that has multiple sheets I am trying to reference to pull together a single sheet of reformatted data.  I am trying to reformat blockchain data from separate CSV files into a single sheet.  Since each csv has a different size, I'm thinking that ARRAYFORMULA will be best to deal with the dynamic length.

Here's my snippet:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK('ERC20'!F2:F),, if(C2:C="transfer-out", QUERY({Txns!A:A,Txns!K:K},"select Col2 where Col1 contains
> '"&K2&"'",0),0)))

I expected this to update K2 (at the end of the query) to K3,K4,K5, etc for the length of the arrayformula

The ISBLANK just checks for a blank cell and proceeds if there is something there. That works fine. the if(C2... condition works as well.

The Query successfully brings in Txns!A and Txns!K, and will meet the contains condition.  However, This value K2, doesn't update for rows 3,4,5, etc.  I have searched trying to find a solution to create this cell reference as dynamic in the array, but can't find anything.  Anyone out there have a tip for me?

I'm sure there's also other ways to get to where I'm going, but this is the way I've stumbled so far...

This VLOOKUP does the same thing, works with K2, but doesn't update:

> =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK('ERC20'!F2:F),, if(C2:C="transfer-out", VLOOKUP(K2,{Txns!A:A,Txns!K:K},2,false),0)))

Thanks in advance! Still new with this, so thanks for the hand holding

Answer (score 1):

Answered my own question!  But I think I'll leave it here for anyone else.

I needed to bring the range into the `VLOOKUP formula- K2:K` worked out!

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK('ERC20'!F2:F),, if(C2:C="transfer-out", VLOOKUP(K2:K,{Txns!A:A,Txns!K:K},2,false),0)))
```